# CustomView in RecyclerView malfunctioning ( items get swapped , disappeared or repeated )

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-custom-view

I am implementing a local chat_box like page, I have two Vectors queued_messages and messages. I remove items from queued list and add to the messages and wait in the asynctask to add other items.three kind of messages sent received and multiple choice questions.multiple choice questions have the problems in the title.(especially if you scroll to top page while they get loading)

1.I have already set has fixed size to true
2.tried making custom view directly in adapter instead of inflating a view containing it 
3.set is recyclable to off and implemented both selected and unselected mode in onbindviewholder
4.tried different kind of notifies.
5.disabled scroll to last position

my Adapter:

```java
public class MessageListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

    private List<Message> messages;

    MessageListAdapter(List<Message> messages) {
        this.messages = messages;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view;
        if (i == Message.RECEIVED_MESSAGE) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recieved_message, viewGroup, false);
            return new Received_Message_Holder(view);
        } else if (i == Message.MULTIPLE_CHOICE) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.multiple_choice_item, viewGroup, false);
            return new Multiple_Choice_Holder(view);
        } else if (i == Message.SENT_MESSAGE) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.sent_message, viewGroup, false);
            return new Sent_Message_Holder(view);
        }else
            return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        Message message = messages.get(position);
        return message.getType();
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        Message msg = messages.get(i);
        if (msg.getType() == Message.RECEIVED_MESSAGE)
            ((Received_Message_Holder) viewHolder).bind(msg);
        else if (msg.getType() == Message.MULTIPLE_CHOICE) {
            //viewHolder.setIsRecyclable(false);
            ((Multiple_Choice_Holder) viewHolder).bind((Question) msg);
        }
        else if (msg.getType() == Message.SENT_MESSAGE)
            ((Sent_Message_Holder) viewHolder).bind(msg);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return messages.size();
    }

}

class Received_Message_Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView messageText, timeText, nameText;
    ImageView profileImage;

    Received_Message_Holder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        messageText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_message_body);
        timeText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_message_time);
        nameText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_message_name);
        profileImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_message_profile);
    }

    void bind(Message message) {
        messageText.setText(message.getMessage());

        timeText.setText(message.get_date());

        nameText.setText(message.getSender().getNickname());

        // Insert the profile image from the URL into the ImageView.
        profileImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.male);
    }
}

class Sent_Message_Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView name, text, time;
    ImageView profile_image;

    public Sent_Message_Holder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_message_name);
        text = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_message_body);
        time = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_message_time);
        profile_image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_message_profile);
    }

    void bind(Message message) {
        text.setText(message.getMessage());

        time.setText(message.get_date());

        name.setText(message.getSender().getNickname());

        // Insert the profile image from the URL into the ImageView.
        profile_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.male);
    }
}

class Multiple_Choice_Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    Collection_Picker picker;

    Multiple_Choice_Holder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        picker = itemView.findViewById(R.id.collection_picker);
    }

    void bind(Question question) {

        List<Choice_Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < question.getOptions().size(); i++) {
            items.add(new Choice_Item(String.valueOf(i), question.getOptions().get(i)));
        }
        if(question.getAnsPosition() != -1)
        {
            Log.wtf("TAg","redraw");
            picker.draw_fixed(items.get(question.getAnsPosition()));
        }else {
            Log.wtf("TAg","drwing from zero");
            picker.setItems(items);
            picker.setListener(question.getListener());
        }
    }
}
```

And the Activity which uses this:

```
public class Chat_activity extends AppCompatActivity  implements questionListener{

    Vector<Message> queued_messages = new Vector<>();
    List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<>() ;
    RecyclerView recyclerView ;
    MessageListAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.chat_page_activity);


        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.reyclerview_message_list);

        init_messages();

        LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
        adapter = new MessageListAdapter(messages);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        start_chat_show();

     //edit text also add sent message to messages
    }
    int evaluate_message_size(Message message){
        return message.getMessage().length()*50;
    }

    void start_chat_show(){
        new async_task(evaluate_message_size(queued_messages.get(0))).execute();
    }

    @Override
    public void onQuestionAnswered(int ansPosition) {
        afterQuestion(ansPosition);
    }

    class async_task extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

        int time_interval = 200;

        public async_task(int time_interval){
            super();
            this.time_interval = time_interval;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(time_interval);
            }catch (InterruptedException e){
                Log.d("Tavak", "real errors!");
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
           next_message();
        }
    }

    private void next_message(){
        if(queued_messages.size()>0) {
            messages.add(queued_messages.get(0));
            queued_messages.remove(0);
            Log.wtf("tag", String.valueOf(messages.size()));
            adapter.notifyItemInserted(messages.size()-1);
            if (messages.get(messages.size() - 1).getType() == Message.MULTIPLE_CHOICE) {
                lastQuestionPosition = messages.size() - 1;
            }
            if (queued_messages.size() > 0 && messages.get(messages.size() - 1).getType() != Message.MULTIPLE_CHOICE && !messages.get(messages.size() - 1).isHas_input())
                new async_task(evaluate_message_size(messages.get(messages.size() - 1))).execute();
           // recyclerView.scrollToPosition(adapter.getItemCount());
        }

    }

    public void afterQuestion(int ansPosition){
        ((Question)messages.get(lastQuestionPosition)).setAnsPosition(ansPosition);
        ((Question)messages.get(lastQuestionPosition)).actOnAnswer();
        if(queued_messages.size()>0)
          next_message();
    }

    private void questionChild(int position){
        User user = new User();
        user.setNickname("us");

        Message msg4 = new Message();
        msg4.setSender(user);
        msg4.setMessage("what kind are you?");
        msg4.setHas_input(true);
        queued_messages.add(position+1,msg4);

        Message msg5 = new Message();
        msg5.setSender(user);
        msg5.setMessage("whats up?");
        msg5.setHas_input(true);
        queued_messages.add(position+2,msg5);

        Message msg5_5 = new Message();
        msg5_5.setSender(user);
        msg5_5.setMessage("repeat process?");
        queued_messages.add(msg5_5);

        Question msg6 = new Question();
        msg6.setSender(user);
        msg6.setQuestion("repeat process?");
        Vector<String> options0 = new Vector<>();
        options0.add("yes");
        options0.add("no");
        msg6.setOptions(options0);
        msg6.setListener(this);
        msg6.setItem_listener(new questionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onQuestionAnswered(int ansPosition) {
                if(ansPosition == 0){
                    questionChild(-1);
                }
            }
        });
        queued_messages.add(position+3,msg6);
    }

    private void init_messages(){

        final User user = new User();
        user.setNickname("us");

        Message msg = new Message();
        msg.setSender(user);
        msg.setMessage("hello");
        queued_messages.add(msg);

        Message msg2 = new Message();
        msg2.setSender(user);
        msg2.setMessage("welcome to your place");
        queued_messages.add(msg2);

        Message msg3 = new Message();
        msg3.setSender(user);
        msg3.setMessage("good luck");
        queued_messages.add(msg3);

        Message msg4 = new Message();
        msg4.setSender(user);
        msg4.setMessage("what kind is it?");
        msg4.setHas_input(true);
        queued_messages.add(msg4);

        Message msg5 = new Message();
        msg5.setSender(user);
        msg5.setMessage("how old؟");
        msg5.setHas_input(true);
        queued_messages.add(msg5);

        Message msg5_5 = new Message();
        msg5_5.setSender(user);
        msg5_5.setMessage("any other one?");
        queued_messages.add(msg5_5);

        Question msg6 = new Question();
        msg6.setSender(user);
        msg6.setQuestion("any other one?");
        Vector<String> options0 = new Vector<>();
        options0.add("yes");
        options0.add("no");
        msg6.setOptions(options0);
        msg6.setListener(this);
        msg6.setItem_listener(new questionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onQuestionAnswered(int ansPosition) {
                if(ansPosition == 0){
                    questionChild(-1);
                }
            }
        });
        queued_messages.add(msg6);

        Message msg6_5 = new Message();
        msg6_5.setSender(user);
        msg6_5.setMessage("your problem?");
        queued_messages.add(msg6_5);

        Question q = new Question();
        q.setQuestion("your problem?");
        Vector<String> options = new Vector<>();
        options.add("Im feeling bad");
        options.add("stuck in my room");
        options.add("kidnapped");
        options.add("none of above");
        q.setOptions(options);
        q.setListener(this);
        q.setItem_listener(new questionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onQuestionAnswered(int ansPosition) {
                if(ansPosition == 0){
                    next_message();
                }
            }
        });
        queued_messages.add(q);

        Message msg9 = new Message();
        msg9.setSender(user);
        msg9.setMessage("Its natural");
        queued_messages.add(msg9);

        Message msg10 = new Message();
        msg10.setSender(user);
        msg10.setMessage("easilly solvabe.");
        queued_messages.add(msg10);

        Message msg11 = new Message();
        msg11.setSender(user);
        msg11.setMessage("join us and learn.");
        queued_messages.add(msg11);

        Message msg12 = new Message();
        msg12.setSender(user);
        msg12.setMessage("wanna join us؟");
        queued_messages.add(msg12);

        Question q2 = new Question();
        q2.setQuestion("wanna join us?");
        Vector<String> options1 = new Vector<>();
        options1.add("yes");
        options1.add("no");
        q2.setOptions(options1);
        q2.setListener(this);
        q2.setItem_listener(new questionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onQuestionAnswered(int ansPosition) {
                if(ansPosition == 0){
                    Toast.makeText(Chat_activity.this,"we;re set to go",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent mintent  = new Intent(Chat_activity.this,Khans_activity.class);
                    startActivity(mintent);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        });
        queued_messages.add(q2);

    }
}
```

I wish that recyclerview works correctly(without any disappearing , repeated values or swaped items).
Please inform me if you need any further detail.

Comment: maybe I should switch to list views :/

Comment: the problem seems to be in custom view I called redraw in it and some problems resolved.